# How do you access loopback model property types? (model.definition.properties.type)

Tags: javascript, types, loopbackjs

How can you access the model property types from within a model extension file (model.js)?

If I try to access MODEL.definition.properties I'm able to see the following for a given property:

```
{ type: [Function: String],
[1]   required: false,
[1]   description: 'deal stage' }
```

Why is the type listed as `[Function: String]` instead of just "String" or something of the sort?

If I run `typeof(property.type)` it returns "function", but if I run `property.type()` it returns an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I am a co-author and a current maintainer of LoopBack.*

**TL;DR**

Use the following expression to obtain the property type as a string name. Please note it works only for a subset of possible property definitions (see later), most notably it does not support arrays.

```
const type = typeof property.type === 'string' 
  ? property.type
  : property.type.modelName || property.type.name;
```

**The long version**

LoopBack allows the property type to be defined in several ways:

1. As a string name, e.g. `{type: 'string', description: 'deal stage'}`. You can use a model name as the type too, e.g. `{type: 'Customer'}`.
2. As a type constructor, e.g. `{type: String, description: 'deal stage'}`. You can use a model constructor as the type too, e.g. `{type: Customer}`.
3. As a definition of an anonymous model, e.g. `{type: {street: String, city: String, country: String}`
4. As an array type. The type of array items can be specified using any of the three ways described above (as a string name, a type constructor or an anonymous model definition).

Read more in our documentation: [LoopBack types](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/LoopBack-types.html)

To better understand how to process different kinds of property definitions, you can check the code in loopback-swagger that is converting a LoopBack model schema into Swagger Schema (which is similar to JSON Schema):

- [buildFromLoopBackType](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-swagger/blob/8f845d4450792ee0bc6d93fd67e055e3705650f2/lib/specgen/schema-builder.js#L61-L134)
- [getLdlTypeName](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-swagger/blob/8f845d4450792ee0bc6d93fd67e055e3705650f2/lib/specgen/schema-builder.js#L140-L172)

The function `getLdlTypeName` takes a property definition (slightly normalized by `buildFromLoopBackType`) on the input and returns the property type as a string name.

```
exports.getLdlTypeName = function(ldlType) {
  // Value "array" is a shortcut for `['any']`
  if (ldlType === 'array') {
    return ['any'];
  }

  if (typeof ldlType === 'string') {
    var arrayMatch = ldlType.match(/^\[(.*)\]$/);
    return arrayMatch ? [arrayMatch[1]] : ldlType;
  }

  if (typeof ldlType === 'function') {
    return ldlType.modelName || ldlType.name;
  }

  if (Array.isArray(ldlType)) {
    return ldlType;
  }

  if (typeof ldlType === 'object') {
    // Anonymous objects, they are allowed e.g. in accepts/returns definitions
    // TODO(bajtos) Build a named schema for this anonymous object
    return 'object';
  }

  if (ldlType === undefined) {
    return 'any';
  }

  var msg = g.f('Warning: unknown LDL type %j, using "{{any}}" instead', ldlType);
  console.error(msg);
  return 'any';
};
```

Comment: Miroslav, thanks for the detailed answer! Going to try this out.

Answer (score 0):

Running `typeof` on the function returns the type.

`var type = typeof(property.type())`

var `type` will be string, number, etc.

Not sure why loopback doesn't return the type itself, instead of a function.